# PHP to Excel File: column shows formula as string

Tags: php, excel

I have a problem with some column of my excel file that I export from php. Another column is working fine with the formula but another two columns have a problem.

1. A column with formula does not execute the formula but shows the formula
   as a string, the formula will be working/execute normally when the user clicks on the column and the presses Enter. It's no problem if I just have a couple of rows on the file that need to execute manually, but if there's lot of rows then a lot of work should be done.
2. Another column has the same problem but this only happens on the first six rows, the rest of the rows are working normally.

I think this not a problem with the formula, because the formula is just working fine when I hit enter on the cell to execute manually.

How can I solve this?

Here is a screenshot of the column:

[image]

Here is my code of header:

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;");
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Laporan_Absensi_".date("d-m-Y").date("_H-i"));
```

For the problem of point 1., here is the code how I set the column:

```
<td style="vnd.ms-excel.numberformat:#,##0_) \Rp;" align="right"><?=$penalty?></td>
```

For the problem of point 2., here is the code how I set the column:

```
<td style="background-color:#99CCFF;vnd.ms-excel.numberformat:h:mm;" align="right"><?=$form?></td>
```

`$penalty` and `$form` is the variable where I store the formula.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `some_table`'); 
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records'); 
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result); 
$headers = array(); 
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
{     
   $headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i); 
} 
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w'); 
if ($fp && $result) 
{     
   header('Content-Type: text/csv');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
   header('Pragma: no-cache');    
   header('Expires: 0');
   fputcsv($fp, $headers); 
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
   {
      fputcsv($fp, array_values($row)); 
   }
die; 
}
```

Comment: why using `csv` instead of using `vnd.ms-excel`?